# Problems with fold in Rust

Tags: fold, rust

Let's assume `fn scan(int, int) -> int`.

When using

```
fn count(x: int, y: int) -> int
{
    scan(x - 1, y - 1) + scan(x - 1, y) + scan(x - 1, y + 1) + scan(x, y - 1)
        + scan(x, y + 1) + scan(x + 1, y - 1) + scan(x + 1, y) + scan(x + 1, y + 1)
}
```

I get correct results. I am trying to get the same results by `fold`ing the `scan` function over the given value ranges; however, I can't seem to get it right. My current attempt is

```
fn count_fold(x: int, y: int) -> int
{
    std::iter::range_inclusive(-1, 1).zip(std::iter::range_inclusive(-1, 1)).fold(0, |a, (i, j)| { a + scan(x + i, y + j) })
}
```

which seems to return only a subset of the correct results. What am I doing wrong? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you **zip** two iterators, you are not creating the "product" of the iterations, like you seem to be wanting to do. Rather, you are iterating both iterators at the same time and creating a pair with the iterated values. So in the `count_fold` version, the closure  will only be called with the following pairs:

```
(-1, -1)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
```

So your `count_fold` function is actually akin to

```
scan(x - 1, y - 1) + scan(x, y) + scan(x - 1, y + 1)
```

I can be wrong, but I don't think there is a function in `std` that create the product of two iterators.

Moreover, your `count` method do not use `scan(x, y)` in the sum, so it is not even really the product of the iterators; you have to be careful about that if you want to create your own product iterator and use it for that purpose.

Comment: To clarify things a bit, I don't need `scan(x, y)` there. The idea is to scan [sic] the Moore neighbourhood of the given coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

Cyrille is correct in saying there is no iterator-product function. However, one can manually take the product of the two iterators by folding twice:

```
use std::iter::range_inclusive;

fn count_fold(x: int, y: int) -> int {
    range_inclusive(-1, 1).fold(0, 
         |a, i| range_inclusive(-1, 1).fold(a, |b, j| b + scan(x + i, y + j)))
}
```

Although it looks like you'll need to filter the case when `i == 0 && j == 0`, i.e.

```
fn count_fold(x: int, y: int) -> int {
    range_inclusive(-1, 1).fold(0, 
         |a, i| range_inclusive(-1, 1).fold(a, 
             |b, j| if i == 0 && j == 0 {b} else {b + scan(x + i, y + j)}))
}
```

or

```
fn count_fold(x: int, y: int) -> int {
    range_inclusive(-1, 1).fold(0, 
         |a, i| range_inclusive(-1, 1)
             .filter(|&j| !(i == 0 && j == 0))
             .fold(a, |b, j| b + scan(x + i, y + j)))
}
```

However, I'd almost say that this is clearer imperatively:

```
fn count_fold(x: int, y: int) -> int {
    let mut a = 0;
    for i in range_inclusive(-1, 1) {
        for j in range_inclusive(-1, 1) {
            if !(i == 0 && j == 0) { a += scan(x + i, y + j) }
        }
    }
    a
}
```

Comment: That's strange. Your imperative version, just like mine, yields correct results but your functional version doesn't work (also, `scan` filters cases when `i == 0 && j == 0` so `count` doesn't need to do that).